# Retrofit with Gson Response.body() not working

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'am trying to parse data to a recyclerview, i had some problems about expecting JSONArray/JSONObject that i fixed with some help, but this moment I am a little bit lost in what to do in the `Onresponse`, the original - `generatePhonesList(response.body())` isnt working.

this is my json and i am trying to parse the data inside the `array results[]` :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "metadata": {
    "sort": "POPULARITY",
    "total_products": 20,
    "title": "Phones & Tablets",
    "results": [
      {
        "sku": "1",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy S9",
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "max_saving_percentage": 30,
        "price": 53996,
        "special_price": 37990,
        "image": "https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s9-.jpg",
        "rating_average": 5
      },
```

MainActivity (CALL and Recyclerview creation) :

```
    GetPhoneDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetPhoneDataService.class);

        Call<APIReponse> call = service.getAllPhones();

       call.enqueue(new Callback<APIReponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<APIReponse> call, Response<APIReponse> response) {
              generatePhonesList(response.body());


           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<APIReponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("eee" , "" + t.getMessage());
           }
       });

    }

    private void generatePhonesList(List<Result> phonesList){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new PhonesAdapter(phonesList,this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

this is the POJO Class's created in jsonschema2pojo :

```
public class APIReponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("metadata")
    @Expose
    private Metadata metadata;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

}
```

2 class

```
public class MetaData {
    @SerializedName("sort")
    @Expose
    private String sort;
    @SerializedName("total_products")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalProducts;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = null;

    public String getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public void setSort(String sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public Integer getTotalProducts() {
        return totalProducts;
    }

    public void setTotalProducts(Integer totalProducts) {
        this.totalProducts = totalProducts;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

3 class:

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    @Expose
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("max_saving_percentage")
    @Expose
    private Integer maxSavingPercentage;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private Integer price;
    @SerializedName("special_price")
    @Expose
    private Integer specialPrice;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("rating_average")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingAverage;

    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public Integer getMaxSavingPercentage() {
        return maxSavingPercentage;
    }

    public void setMaxSavingPercentage(Integer maxSavingPercentage) {
        this.maxSavingPercentage = maxSavingPercentage;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getSpecialPrice() {
        return specialPrice;
    }

    public void setSpecialPrice(Integer specialPrice) {
        this.specialPrice = specialPrice;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Integer getRatingAverage() {
        return ratingAverage;
    }

    public void setRatingAverage(Integer ratingAverage) {
        this.ratingAverage = ratingAverage;
    }
}
```

Comment: are u getting Http code as 200?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal, no in the failure i get "error: incompatible types: APIReponse cannot be converted to List<Result>", the Call is made to APIresponse and the recyclerview its constructed by a list of Results and the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `APIReponse` model to the `generatePhonesList(List<Result> phonesList)` function. You need to pass only the list of results in this function.

Replace this:

```
generatePhonesList(response.body());
```

with:

```
generatePhonesList(response.body().getMetadata().getResults());
```

Here getMetadata() and getResults() are the getter functions of metadata model and List.

Comment: i tried but the getResults cant be call, give the classic red color, do you think is any problem with the class's ?

Comment: @vpedro72 You have to create a getter function in the Metadata model for the List<Result>.

Comment: i have already in the MetaData class i have the propreties and getters and setters for <ListResults>

Comment: @vpedro72 Your function name maybe different for the getResults. Check your function name and call the getter function.

Comment: @Sugat i fixed the MetaData was a kotlin object and not the Class

Answer (score 1):

If you pay close attention `response.body()` will provide you with class `APIResponse`. But you need is `List<Result>`. To achieve this, try `response.body().getMetadata().getResults()`

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer however you can check my answer as well and give an upvote maybe. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the ansewer @Rahul , i tried but after the getMetaData. i dont get the getResult

Comment: then maybe you are not getting the data in the api. check in postman.